# Published mvc app loading forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I've published an MVC application on IIS 7.5 on external server. But when i run it it just says "Waiting for..." and nothing is happening! No errors, no application logs (because the application didn't even started), no IIS logs, no errors/warnings in event viewer.  Can you tell me what can I do to track what is going on? Keep in mind that in development environment everything works fine. Also I already published the same application on another server and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

the best you can do is to add [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to your project and see its reports,

btw, if you are using a shared host it could be a memory limitation, slow CPU, slow bandwidth,....a lot of possibilities....